# Angular2: get elementref on child component from parent

Tags: angular

I'm trying the get an ElementRef for a child component from its parent component.

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'parent',
templateUrl: 'parent.component.html',
directives: [
  Child1Component,
  Child2Component
  ]
})
```

In the html for `Child1Component` I have

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" #myRef>Select File</button>
```

In the class for the parent:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('myRef') myRef: ElementRef;
  // ...
```

But of course when I try to access the child ElementRef in the parent class...

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.myRef.nativeElement);
```

...I get `undefined`. How should I get the ElementRef? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of any way for a parent component to be able to reference a local template variable defined in a child component template.  Consider having the parent get a reference to the child component using @ViewChild, then you can call a method on the child component to manipulate the element of interest.

Answer (score 6):

You can now do this.

```
@ViewChild('myRef', {read: ElementRef}) myRef: ElementRef
```

By default Angular will grab the component reference if your template reference variable is attached to a custom component. The `read` option tells angular which token to pull, so you can explicitly tell it to pull the `ElementRef` token instead of the class instance of whatever component you are trying to read.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed

```
@ViewChild('myRef', { static: true, read: ElementRef }) myRef!: ElementRef
```

Answer (score 0):

try using ContentChild instead of ViewChild

```
import { Component, ContentChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChild('myRef') myRef: ElementRef;
  // ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.myRef.nativeElement);
  }

}
```

Comment: @chris_r: That last comment of yours in your [recently deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117690/custom-pegman-icon-for-street-view-google-maps-api-v3#comment95103751_54117690) was completely uncalled for and is the sort of comment that can get you banned from this site. Moderators have been notified of your behavior.